# How do you get details from the output of the locate command?

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, locate

When I run the `ls -l` command I get details about the files in the current directory like permissions, owner, group, file size.

Is there a way I can get these same details instead of just the location of the file when I run `locate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `locate` database do not contain information other that names, so you should run some other tool, like `ls`, on `locate` output

```
lsloc() {
  locate "$@" | 
    while read -r name; do
      ls -ld "$name"
    done
}
lsloc pattern
```

Answer (score 5):

Pipe the output of `locate` to `xargs` (adding `ls -l` as parameters to `xargs`).  This lets you use whatever options you need with either command.  By also passing the `-0` (dash-zero) option to both commands, you also protect against unintended interpretations of blanks or newlines in filenames.  For example, to get the details of all .iso files on my system:

```
locate -0 -r '.*.iso$' | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a subshell

```
ls -l "`locate -b 'search_pattern'`"
```

Or

```
ls -lh "$(locate -b 'search_pattern')"
```

You can add a function to ~/.bashrc if you wish

```
function lsloc () { ls -l "$(locate -b "$1") ;}
```

You then

```
lsloc "search pattern"
```

Comment: Do not work if results contain spaces.

Comment: Yes it does, but as you know files with spaces are more complex. `lsloc 'file\ with\ space'`

Comment: I talked about locate output, not pattern.

Comment: I understand, but, as you know, bash does not like file names with spaces, and the output of locate includes spaces. I modified my post and it now works with files with spaces.

Comment: No, it still don't work every time you have more than one result.

Comment: You have a valid point, and a good script, hats off to you. You certainly have pointed out the nuances of `locate`, the output of locate, and the potential problems of using spaces in file names with bash. My interest in debugging this is so low I would have switched to an alternate solution (find) long ago and typically avoid spaces in file names for just such reasons.