# subshell ls -lh "$(find /music -type d)" doesn't return list, instead results of find command

Tags: bash, command-line, find, ls

I'm trying to list the details of all the directories in my music folder using the following command:

```
ls -lh "$(find /music -type d)"
```

However all I get is the return of the find command.  Is this syntax correct?  I'm using ubuntu server 10.04.  I think I remember a few weeks ago trying this on gui ubuntu 10.04 and it seemed to output the details of the ls command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, without the quotes

```
ls -lh $(find /music -type d)
```

With the quotes ls -l sees the find as a single file rather then a list of items. Look closer at the output , do you not see

```
ls: cannot access ...
list of find results
last item : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Yeah, what caught me off guard is my file names contain spaces so I can't do an ls on the return of the find command

Comment: There is a discussion here http://askubuntu.com/questions/91072/how-do-you-get-details-from-the-output-of-the-locate-command that covers files with spaces